# I'm getting error of .html extension not recognized using node command

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got project from my client to update that project with some points. But I'm facing problem to run this project.

I install npm and all required node modules downloaded based on package.json information.

```
    {
  "name": "acelle-builder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "type" : "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/ace": "0.0.42",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "raw-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "svg-url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "url-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ace-builds": "^1.4.12",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-beautify": "^1.13.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```

there are some codes of importing html files like

```
    import controls from './controls.html';
import widgets from './widgets.html';
```

but when I run this project using node command I'm getting error with unknown file .html extension.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js can only import JS modules.

If you want to use syntax which involves importing other kinds of things then you need to use an appropriate tool. The dependencies in the `package.json` file include WebPack. Use that.

There is even a script (named `build`) listed that will run it.

```
npm run build
```

Comment: yes. I know build command which gives bundle minified files using webpack . using bundled minified files I'm getting output . but I wanted to run this application with unminified source files so that I can add some extra features and check output instantly .

Comment: You can’t. It isn’t written in plain JS, you *need* the bundler to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import from an html file. You are trying to import from ./controls.html and ./widgets.html. You have to import from js files. Maybe you meant "./controls.html" and "./widgets.js".